# How can I prevent Contribution Pages forcing the email to be of type Billing

Tags: civicontribute, location-type

Only just stumbled on this after realising that a client was correct. They set the Profile to use Email (home) but the Contribution page overrides this and makes the email be Billing.

This ticket seems closest to the [issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16339) though it is initially about the idea of being able to collect additional email addresses.

If John K is correct then current approach is

- If the contact is logged in this field defaults to the 'Billing' email, if set, otherwise the 'primary' email
- When the contribution is confirmed the email address is saved/updated on the contact as the 'Billing' email

(ie: If the field was prefilled from the primary 'home' email, the contact would now have two email addresses the same for 'home' and 'billing')

Comment: We are looking at getting an alternative to this out as an Extension

Comment: Have you made any progress with this extension? We have a client with the same issue.

Comment: Heather - can you pm me. peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create your own custom module/plugin to do what is required. Steps:

1. Use hook_civicrm_postProcess hook for the target contribution page, you can give the contribution id or name in if condition.
2. Use civicrm contact create api call to edit email address type.

Comment: thx. we have created an extension but waiting on QA by client before releasing

Comment: pls have a look at the extension published in another answer on this ticket

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension [here](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.emailprofile) which includes email fields in profiles on the contribution page. The standard billing email address field is removed when an email field is found in profile.

If the contact is logged in - this field defaults to the 'Billing' email, if set, otherwise it is set to 'primary'.

When the contribution is confirmed the email address is saved/updated on the contact as the 'Billing' email